# Continue work on main activity while Socket.read() is active

Tags: java, android

I have an app that use as client and send and receive data from the server.
after the first connection i want to be in socket.read() all the time to be ready for the to sent me some data data.
the problem is while i am in socket.read() the user cant do anything in the app like send a new data to the server and so..

this is run on doInBackground in asyncTask.

```
  InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                int read = inputStream.read(buffer);
                int bytesRead = read;
                if (read == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                response = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                break;
            }
```

Comment: You mean that `AsyncTask. doInBackground ` runs in main thread?

Comment: No, the AsyncTask run on outside class from the MainActivity